# How do i make an object respawn?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a game in roblox, ( a sinking ship game ) and I need to know how to make the ship respawn after the ships sinks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you need a place to start, take a look at the Clone() function. https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/Clone

Answer (score 0):

If you need a place to start, take a look at the Clone() function [here.](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/Clone)

The code below can be used to clone and insert a copy of a model. Make sure to clone your ship before you remove it however.

```lua
-- Get a reference to an existing object
   local original = workspace.Model
-- Create the model copy
   local copy = original:Clone()
-- Parent the copy to the same parent as the original
   copy.Parent = original.Parent
-- Move the copy so it's not overlapping the original
   copy:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(0, 50, 0))
```